# How to set Tabulator groupValues outside of initial setup

Tags: tabulator

When creating a tabulator table one can set the groupBy options using something like:

`groupBy: ["CapType"],`
`groupValues: [["Large", "Medium", "Small", "Micro"]],`

However there doesn't seem to be a similar method to change the groupValues after the table has already been created, like you can using `table.setGroupBy("")`

Is there a function I have missed in the docs?

I want to do this to pretty up the group names instead of using the raw values extracted from the table.

Comment: at the moment you would have to redeclare the table to change this. but it sounds like a useful addition to the table. have you through about raising a feature request on the GitHub repo?

Comment: Done. Thanks.
https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/issues/2928